# NOAUTH Authentication required - deploying with Heroku (Channel 2.0.2 - Django 2.0.2 - Heroku-Redis)

Tags: django, heroku, redis, django-channels

I am trying to run the multichat example of Channels 2.0.2 (Django 2.0.2) @ Heroku with heroku-redis.
But I'm getting NOAUTH Authentication required (btw: I am able to run locally):

```
    2018-02-20T02:16:34.648943+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.45.77.75:32339 - - [20/Feb/2018:02:16:34] "WSCONNECTING /chat/stream/" - -
    2018-02-20T02:16:34.649549+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-02-20 02:16:34,649 DEBUG    Upgraded connection ['10.45.77.75', 32339] to WebSocket
    2018-02-20T02:16:34.650407+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-02-20 02:16:34,650 DEBUG    Creating tcp connection to ('ec2-34-238-60-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com', 28169)
    2018-02-20T02:16:34.659050+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-02-20 02:16:34,658 DEBUG    WebSocket ['10.45.77.75', 32339] open and established
    2018-02-20T02:16:34.659217+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.45.77.75:32339 - - [20/Feb/2018:02:16:34] "WSCONNECT /chat/stream/" - -
    2018-02-20T02:16:34.659974+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-02-20 02:16:34,659 DEBUG    WebSocket ['10.45.77.75', 32339] accepted by application
    2018-02-20T02:16:34.666248+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-02-20 02:16:34,666 DEBUG    Closed 0 connection(s)
    2018-02-20T02:16:35.085802+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-02-20 02:16:35,085 ERROR    Exception inside application: NOAUTH Authentication required.
    2018-02-20T02:16:35.085814+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 54, in __call__
    2018-02-20T02:16:35.085816+00:00 app[web.1]:     await await_many_dispatch([receive, self.channel_receive], self.dispatch)
    2018-02-20T02:16:35.085818+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/utils.py", line 47, in await_many_dispatch
    2018-02-20T02:16:35.085820+00:00 app[web.1]:     result = task.result()
    2018-02-20T02:16:35.085822+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 160, in receive
    2018-02-20T02:16:35.085824+00:00 app[web.1]:     return await self.receive_buffer_lpop(channel)
    2018-02-20T02:16:35.085826+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 222, in receive_buffer_lpop
    2018-02-20T02:16:35.085828+00:00 app[web.1]:     task.result()
    2018-02-20T02:16:35.085829+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 173, in receive_loop
    2018-02-20T02:16:35.085831+00:00 app[web.1]:     real_channel, message = await self.receive_single(channel)
    2018-02-20T02:16:35.085833+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 189, in receive_single
    2018-02-20T02:16:35.085835+00:00 app[web.1]:     pool = await self.connection(index)
    2018-02-20T02:16:35.085836+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 386, in connection
    2018-02-20T02:16:35.085838+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.pools[index] = await aioredis.create_redis_pool(**self.hosts[index])
    2018-02-20T02:16:35.085840+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/commands/__init__.py", line 197, in create_redis_pool
    2018-02-20T02:16:35.085842+00:00 app[web.1]:     loop=loop)
    2018-02-20T02:16:35.085843+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/pool.py", line 56, in create_pool
    2018-02-20T02:16:35.085845+00:00 app[web.1]:     await pool._fill_free(override_min=False)
    2018-02-20T02:16:35.085847+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/pool.py", line 391, in _fill_free
    2018-02-20T02:16:35.085848+00:00 app[web.1]:     await conn.execute('ping')
    2018-02-20T02:16:35.085903+00:00 app[web.1]:   NOAUTH Authentication required.
    2018-02-20T02:16:35.258329+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-02-20 02:16:35,258 DEBUG    WebSocket closed for ['10.45.77.75', 32339]
    2018-02-20T02:16:35.258485+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.45.77.75:32339 - - [20/Feb/2018:02:16:35] "WSDISCONNECT /chat/stream/" - -
```

my settings.py has the following (I've sent the password to the logs and it is matching the one informed by heroku's site (credentials) )

```
redis_url = urlparse(os.environ.get('REDIS_URL'))

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
         "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
         "LOCATION": "{0}:{1}".format(redis_url.hostname, redis_url.port),
         "OPTIONS": {
             "PASSWORD": redis_url.password,
             "DB": 0,
         },
         "CONFIG": {"hosts": [(redis_url.hostname, redis_url.port)]},
    }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to get it working?